# Uber's Home Screen Transition Scroll - iOS (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an app that has the same layout as Uber's Home screen on iOS. There is a section at the bottom of the app that should be scrollable all the way to the top and allow the user to interact with a collection view in the same way that Uber does it. I have attached some screen shots of my app layout below.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do it the scrolling aspect that moved the view and collection view to the top off the of the app while allow interaction with the map behind the content.

I thought of overlaying a scroll view over the map and offsetting it, but the problem with this is the user will not be able to interact with the content beneath it in the same way that a user can interact with the map in the uber app.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi.. have you done this? How?

Comment: Please let me know I also want to implement similar animation

Answer (score 0):

You can add the mapview on the view controller's view and then add the container view on top of it, which contains the collection view.
And the gesture on container view, or you can create a handle(a small view) on top of the container view and add gesture to it.
Then to scroll up and down you can use the constraints to change the position.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Thanks.